# How could I get a specific data in dataframe through using index and columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ipython

I want to get the position of some data.

This is a part of my data:
[image]

partial_coe[0] is my data's variable's name.

I want to get a data like this, using index and columns:

partial_coe[0].iloc['(600000.SH, 600015.SH)']['600000.SH']

But the error is below:

```
TypeError: cannot do positional indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [(600000.SH, 600015.SH)] of <class 'str'>
```

How to get this data using the index and columns?

Comment: Please read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and edit your post correspondingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following if your DF has a Multi-Index:

```
partial_coe[0].loc[('600000.SH', '600015.SH'), '600000.SH']
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, it is not useful. Thank you all the same, I will try again later.